# Nothing happens when cell from tableview is tapped

Tags: swift, uitableview

I create a tableview menu and I want that when you tapping one cell to show the specific  storyboard. Menu is formatted from 4 cell( so 4 different storyboard)

Here is my code:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        _ = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!
        if let _ = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath){
        if indexPath.row == 0{
            print("User choose to buy ticket")
            self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SearchPage")
        }else if indexPath.row == 1{
            print("User choose to check the train status")
            self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("TrainStatusPage")
        }else if indexPath.row == 2{
            print("User choose to see the upcoming trips")
            self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("TripsPage")
        }else if indexPath.row == 3{
            print("User wants to know mor about CFR's facility")
            self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("PassengersPage")
        }
        }
    }
```

When i am pressing the cell(does not matter which) the cell become gray and nothing happening.

[image]

[image]

Comment: i think, it would be better to start with segues at this point. Have a look at http://www.codingexplorer.com/segue-swift-view-controllers/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably plan to navigate to the next viewController? Then you need to say so, initializing an instance is only half the job (if this is indeed what you want to do). So *something* like the below:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    var viewController: UIViewController?
    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        viewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SearchPage")
    }else if indexPath.row == 1 {
        viewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("TrainStatusPage")
    }else if indexPath.row == 2 {
        viewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("TripsPage")
    }else if indexPath.row == 3 {
        viewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("PassengersPage")
    }

    if let destination = viewController {
        navigationController?.pushViewController(destination, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use this lines of code:
 _ = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!
        if let _ = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath){

Just check what indexPath.row was received by method didSelectRowAtIndexPath.

So right way will look like this:

```
if indexPath.row == 0{
            print("User choose to buy ticket")
            self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SearchPage")
        }else if indexPath.row == 1{
            print("User choose to check the train status")
            self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("TrainStatusPage")
        }else if indexPath.row == 2{
            print("User choose to see the upcoming trips")
            self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("TripsPage")
        }else if indexPath.row == 3{
            print("User wants to know mor about CFR's facility")
            self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("PassengersPage")
        }
```

and you can add this line to remove selection state from cell:

```
tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath
```